# Running bash multi-line command from windows

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I want to run the following command (taken from [here](http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git)) which is the following:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags |
cut -d / -f 4 |
while read ref
do
  git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
  git branch -D "tags/$ref";
done
```

I have to run this from windows command prompt, but not sure how to pass it using mulitiple lines. I've tried passing it all as one command e.g.:

`bash -c "git for-each-ref ... while read ref.... done`

using multiple parameters:

`bash -c "git for-for-each..." "cut -d..." "while read ref"`

How can I pass multiple lines to bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do (without getting into the role of each newline in parsing this command) is to simply pass the newlines as part of the argument:

```
bash -c 'git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads/tags |
  cut -d / -f 4 |
  while read ref
  do
    git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
    git branch -D "tags/$ref";
  done
'
```

That said, the only "important" newline is the one preceding the `do` keyword, and it could also be replaced with a semicolon.

```
bash -c 'git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads/tags | cut -d / -f 4 | while read ref; do git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref"; git branch -D "tags/$ref"; done'
```

(Scroll to see the entire command. Note that the original two semicolons were optional in the multi-line version, but are required in the single-line version to terminate each command in the body of the loop.)

However, only the loop itself needs to be executed by the new instance of `bash`; you can also write something like

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads/tags |
  cut -d / -f 4 |
  bash -c 'while read ref
           do
             git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
             git branch -D "tags/$ref";
           done
           '
```